# By System command

Tags: python

By using system command i want to open '.py' in the notepad.
Ex 
assume i have "Fact.py" file.
Now i want to write a program which will open this file in notepad and we can edit this file.

Answer (score 7):

It's best to use subprocess for this, since this will avoid having to deal with quoting files containing spaces etc for the shell.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['notepad','Fact.py'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

os.system("notepad.exe fact.py")
```

should do it, assuming the Notepad program is in your system's path.